# Problem in theme-settings trying to save and modify file

Tags: 7, files

I have downloaded a template and  what i want to achieve is that i can upload a file from the template option without using the ftp client. I have three slideshows and the code that i have implemented is the following:

```
  $form['busi_settings']['slideshow']['slide3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Slide 3'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['busi_settings']['slideshow']['slide3']['slide3_desc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Slide Description'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide3_desc','participacionciudadana'),
  );
  $form['busi_settings']['slideshow']['slide3']['slide3_url'] = array(
    '#title'        => t('Custom Image File'),
    '#type'         => 'managed_file',
    '#description'  => t('Upload a custom image for your site.'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('slide3_url'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://imagessliders',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
    ),
    );
    $image_custom_index = theme_get_setting('slide3_url');
    if (isset($image_custom_index)) {
        $fid = theme_get_setting('slide3_url');
        $file = file_load($fid);
        if ($file->status == 0) {
            $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
            file_save($file);
            file_usage_add($file, 'slide3_url', 'slide3_url', 1);
            // Sets a Drupal message just for clarity.
            drupal_set_message(t('Image saved.'), 'status');
        }
         if ($file) {
          file_usage_delete($file, 'slide3_url', 'slide3_url', 1);
          file_delete($file);
        }
    }
```

I have a lot of errors, the upload is permanent but i cannot replace or delete an image, having a PDO ERROR in all cases...
While im working with it, i would appreciate any help you can provide me. Thank you.

Comment: What are your errors ?

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 2: INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1418131297 ) en drupal_write_record() (línea 7239 de .../common.inc).

Comment: Another error when trying to upload file: The used file in the field Custom Image File cannot be referenced.